# Pyramid application connecting to MongoDB Replicat

Tags: mongodb, pyramid, pylons

I'm using MongoDB replicat set db deployment (1 primary, 1 secondary, 1 Arbiter), from the production.ini file how can I configure the mongodb.url to always point to the primary server of the Replicat Set.
Right now I deploy the pyramid app server on the current primary server and in the `production.ini` file I have this setting:

```
mongodb.url = Mongodb://primaryServerName:27017
```

The problem is the current primary server can change to become secondary. My question is to know how to make sure that the pyramid is always connected to the primary?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? What kind of settings? Example INI file? What have you tried this far. Edit your question With the current informartion the question is too broad and impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the questions. Please let me know if you have anymore confusion. cheers

Comment: In what kind of conditions the primary server can change? It sounds like this must be handled in the Python code which creates the MongoDB connection, not in the settings file.